# Как настроить генерацию ssl сертификата?

Tags: linux, node.js, ssl, letsencrypt

Сервер Koa.js на Ubuntu 18.4
Как настроить генерацию ssl и автоматизировать его обновление при истечении срока?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @Suvitruf, а если не установлен Nginx. У меня стоит просто koa.js

Comment: @DmitryFilippov лучше так не делать и ставить nginx

Comment: @Suvitruf, а почему?

Comment: если нет Nginx, koa.js придется кормить с ложечки все медленные соединения и постоянно потреблять под это ресурсы. Если есть Nginx, то он отдает весь ответ ему, и этим уже занимается Nginx